# include external lib in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, oauth

how to include external lib in laravel ? for example `twitteroauth.php`. 
no need oauth other packages. because i am converting Symfony code to Laravel. Thanks.

```
Class 'App\Controllers\Front\TwitterOAuth' not found
```

.

```
require_once base_path().'/vendor/twitter/twitteroauth.php';
$twitterOAuth = new TwitterOAuth('app_twitter_consumer_key', 'app_twitter_consumer_secret');
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a namespace problem, Laravel is looking for the class inside the 'App\Controllers\Front' namespace.

If the class is not namespaced, use

```
$twitterOAuth = new \TwitterOAuth('app_twitter_consumer_key', 'app_twitter_consumer_secret');
```

(note the backslash before the classname)

otherwise you need to refer to its namespace, something like `\Twitter\TwitterOAuth` or similar, but only by looking at the class file you can tell.

You could also create an alias for the class. Inside the `app\config\app.php` file search for the `aliases` array and add your class:

```
'Twitter'   => 'TwitterOAuth'   #(or whatever namespace it's in)
```

By the way, why not using a specific package? Have you looked on http://packagist.org to see if there's a Twitter OAuth package already adapted for Laravel? That would make things a lot easier.